unable to install tensorflow_addons
i was trying to run this command-  onnx-tf convert -i yolov8n.onnx -o yolov8_tf
then i encountered this error-
2024-06-25 15:20:44.150147: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0.
2024-06-25 15:20:50.272876: I tensorflow/core/util/port.cc:113] oneDNN custom operations are on. You may see slightly different numerical results due to floating-point round-off errors from different computation orders. To turn them off, set the environment variable TF_ENABLE_ONEDNN_OPTS=0.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in run_code
File "C:\Users\aasth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\Scripts\onnx-tf.exe_main.py", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\aasth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\onnx_tf_init.py", line 1, in 
from . import backend
File "C:\Users\aasth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\onnx_tf\backend.py", line 29, in 
from onnx_tf.common.handler_helper import get_all_backend_handlers
File "C:\Users\aasth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\onnx_tf\common\handler_helper.py", line 3, in 
from onnx_tf.handlers.backend import *  # noqa
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\aasth\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\onnx_tf\handlers\backend\hardmax.py", line 3, in 
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_addons'
i tried installing the module using -  pip install tensorflow-addons
then i got this error- Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-addons (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow-addons
i tried installing with.whl files also but i got the same error.
tensorflow version is 2.16
python verson is 3.12

There is no distribution for Python 3.12, you'll need to downgrade to 3.11.

Currently, TensorFlow Addons does not support Python 3.12, which is why you're unable to find a compatible version for installation.
Using Python 3.11 with a virtual environment is the simplest and most reliable solution.
